# Is it possible to deploy code to an Azure Cloud Service without a build step?

Tags: powershell, azure, asp-classic, azure-cloud-services

We've got some legacy on-premise apps that we're evaluating moving off-site, and we are evaluating all our options. I understand that Azure Web Sites would be a lot easier to setup, but at this point it looks like may need some of the additional control that Cloud Services gives us.

However, everything I've read about Cloud Services so far demonstrates how you build an app and then deploy the build to the cloud. Similarly, you can connect to a Visual Studio Online repository, define builds in VSO, and after a commit, a build is performed and the build is deployed to the cloud.

However, in our case some of our pages are Classic ASP pages. In the event that one of these pages changes, I have not been able to figure out a workflow that allows us to deploy the updated files. Remember, classic ASP files do not have a "build" process; it's like a powershell script that is interpreted at runtime.

There is no Visual Studio solution or project involved with these apps. It's just a package of files we want to upload. For a "proof of concept" I decided to start with the simplest possible "app," a simple "hello.txt" file, and I have not been able to figure out a way to deploy this without "wrapping" it in a Visual Studio solution.

I was hoping that I could use, e.g., [Publish-AzureServiceProject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn495166.aspx), however this appears to need a ServiceDefinition.csdef file, and again, I'm not sure how to do this without setting up solution in Visual Studio--a solution that wouldn't be used for anything.

I have a feeling I'm missing something and just need to find the appropriate publish settings file, or proper use of an Azure cmdlet. Is there a straightforward way to publish a package of files to an Azure Cloud Service?

Answer (score 2):

Josh, you will need to package the files into a deployable package.  This can be achieved using the [cspack](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/gg432988.aspx) commandline tool and a hand-crafted definition file.  Your ASP files would be treated as 'content' in this case.

The easiest way would be just to create stub Visual Studio Solution and include a 'Cloud Service' project to which you add all the ASP files.  This way all your files will be redeployed in the event that your Web Roles require recycling by the Azure fabric.

While this might seem like a big overhead if you need to tweak just a single file, it is the correct way to manage PaaS deployments in Azure. If this process doesn't work for you then you should consider moving to an IaaS VM you fully manage yourself.

Answer (score 1):

One thing that may be helpful is to realize that the web role in Cloud Services are just VM's using IIS. For that reason, you can connect to them just like any other server, via RDP, FTP, etc. Our team often bypasses the overhead of simple things, like deploying a new CSS file, an image, etc. by simply copying it in the old school way.

Again, not sure if this helps you, but old school techniques work just as well. :-)

Comment: But if you do this, aren't your changes going to be destroyed whenever you next republish the app? And what if you have multiple web roles? Do you go to each role instance (VM) and make the same change?

Comment: Hi Josh, Yes to both. If you were to manually add a file for example, you would want to add it to the main project so that on the next formal build it goes as well. Likewise, for each VM you will need to make the same change. That can be automated with scripting. Again, I'm not suggesting that a normal build process is not the way to go. But major builds can be risky, and if all you need to do is minor, it could help.

Comment: That sounds good in theory Simon, but in the real world, it helps to have this access. There is a reason Azure gives you the RDP information to access the machine.

Comment: Daniel, in theory your information is correct, but you should never give this advice without the big caveat that whatever you copy to an Azure PaaS VM *WILL* disappear.  The only question is how long it might take.  It could be minutes or it could be weeks, but it will eventually disappear so it is definitely not something you want to do for a real production site.  It is only useful for scenarios where you are trying to troubleshoot or temporarily test a change.  See http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kwill/archive/2013/09/05/how-to-modify-a-running-azure-service.aspx for some more info.

Comment: Agreed Kwill. My suggestion assumed temporary, testing type tweaks.

Comment: Testing-type tweaks invaribly become production-used code that someone forgets to reverse into source control. I can't count the number of "I lost my updates to my website and it's been down for XX hours" posts I've seen. Just don't do it. Even for simple tweaks.  If you can't fix / reproduce in another location you have a fundamental problem with your build and release management approach.